# how to show multiple news in marquee from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem to retrieve data from mysql to show in marquee,when i go to my webpage it shows only one data from the database in marquee.my question is how to retrieve all the stored data.thank you
    below is the code section:

```
$select="SELECT newsid, headlines from news WHERE uploaddate order by uploaddate desc limit 4";
$rsd=mysql_query($select);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $newsid=$row['newsid'];
    $tittle=$row['headlines'];
    $uploaddate=$rowdata['uploaddate'];
}
```

Comment: On a side note: Please don't use marquees. It has not been cool in the 90s and that has not changed recently.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "only one data" ?

Maybe the problems is here

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $newsid=$row['newsid'];
    $tittle=$row['headlines'];
    $uploaddate=$rowdata['uploaddate'];
}
```

With this you'll overwrite the variables over and over again, so at the end of the loop, you'll get only last record values.

A possible solution is to make an array (of array) and store data into it.

So

```
$result = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $result[] = array('news_id' => $row['newsid'],
                      'title' => $row['headlines'],
                      'upload_date' => $rowdata['uploaddate']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that you are writing to the same variables over and over again

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $newsid=$row['newsid'];
    $tittle=$row['headlines'];
    $uploaddate=$rowdata['uploaddate'];
}
```

You will end up with the last value newsid, title and upload date had, so I suggest you echo the data while in the loop.
example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $newsid=$row['newsid'];
    $tittle=$row['headlines'];
    $uploaddate=$rowdata['uploaddate'];
    printf('<a href="/news.php?story=%d">%s</a> - on %s',$newsid,$title,$uploaddate);
}
```

Or store the data to an array

```
$stories = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $stories[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just u try this..

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
    {
        $newsid=$row['newsid'];
        $tittle=$row['headlines'];
        $uploaddate=$rowdata['uploaddate'];
        $cont.="<a href='newpage.php?$newsid'>$title - $uploaddate</a>";
    }
    echo "<marquee>$cont</marquee>";
```