# i want to know how to echo multiple news in marquee between the table

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show multiple news in marquee from mysql using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014769/how-to-show-multiple-news-in-marquee-from-mysql-using-php)

I want to know how to echo multiple news in marquee between the table, I am able to     echo  only one news, I want to view more than 4 news in home page inside the table using marquee , news is already posted in database . I am using this code:

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$select="SELECT newsid, headlines from news WHERE uploaddate order by uploaddate desc limit 4";

$rsd=mysql_query($select);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $newsid=$row['newsid'];
    $tittle=$row['headlines'];
}


?>
```

In design i am using this code

```
<table >
<tr>
    <td width="87%">
    <marquee style="color: #FF0000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-caps; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold" scrollAmount="2" scrollDelay="20" width="840" bgColor="#CCCCFF" height="24">
     <?php echo $tittle; ?></marquee></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your formatting is broken beyond repair. Consider cleaning it up if you expect any help from anybody.

Comment: You already received numerous answers to your last question you posted less than 24 hours ago...  **Please don't repost questions.**  If you want to receive more attention for an existing question you should use the [Bounty System](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

Comment: `<marquee>`? 1987 called and they want their markup back.

Comment: @Lix: worth only 1 rep, I don't think the [bounty system](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) is available to him, unless someone else offers one on his behalf. Not that I disagree with the intent of your comment.

Comment: @dav - If he hasn't got enough rep then obviously he can't use the bounty system.  It doesn't change the fact that re-posting is not accepted here and not the correct way to increase interest on the post.  Moreover as a new user it is important to make him aware that such a system exists.  He'll have to work on some rep in order to be able to offer a bounty...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your loop....
The part that does this:

```
<?php echo $tittle; ?>
//should be in the loop like below:


<!--starting from the above the loop-->
<table>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)){
        $tittle = $row['headlines'];
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo '<marquee style="color:#ff0000; .......>';
        echo $tittle;
        echo '</marquee>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<marquee >
 <table>
 <?php


 $sql="SELECT newsid,headlines FROM `news` ORDER BY uploaddate DESC LIMIT 4 ";
 $res=func_query($sql);
 foreach($res as $key=>$val)
 {
?>
<tr><td><?=$val['headlines']?>: </h5></td></td>
<tr><td><hr style="border: 1px dotted #B8B8B8;"/></td></tr>

 <?php
  } 
    ?>
</table>
</marquee>
```